# What are simple R equivalent of Panda's fillna methods?

Tags: r, pandas, fillna

In particular I am interested in equivalents of

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

and

```
df.fillna(method='bfill')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(df)
```

and for the second case,

```
na.locf(df, fromLast=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:3, NA), 5*4, replace=TRUE), 5, 4))
```